# react-calendar how to change default date format and disable old date

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I'm using the library: `react-calendar 2.1`
My code:

```
<Calendar 
  onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} 
  activeStartDate={this.state.today}
/>
```

The default date format is: `Tue May 05 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530` (India Standard Time).
I want to change the date format to: `15/05/2020`

I also want to disable backdates.

Comment: i am new to react, kindly help

Comment: What did you try? Please review topics at StackOverflow.com/help, then `edit` to include what you tried, what the result was, & how that differs from your expectations. As is, this looks like a "free coding service" request, & is not worded in a way to help future users solve issues they may run across. It also does not meet SO guidelines for questions we are designed to handle. However a few additional details could fix that. ;-)

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "I want to disable backdates". If it is a separate question, then it is recommended to ask it as a new questing. This keeps different issues/solutions sullied, so future visitors can home in on a specific issue in any one post.

Answer (score 0):

moment(yourValues).format("DD/MM/YYYY")